# Once you have the interval of convergence, how do you find the values of x for which the series converges absolutely and conditionally?

Tags: convergence-divergence

Take this series: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{nx^n}{n+9}.$$

I found the interval of convergence to be $-1 < x < 1$ but how do I approach finding the interval for which the series converges absolutely and conditionally?

I understand that for it to converge absolutely, each term put to the absolute should converge, otherwise it conditionally converges but I'm not sure where to start. Any tips?

Comment: No problem. To get that type `\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{nx^n}{n+9}.`

Comment: @projectilemotion alrightt thanks I'll remember that

Comment: How did you determine the interval of convergence?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I solved the inequality |x-a| < R for x to find the 2 end-points

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos What does it mean if the series at both the endpoints diverge? Does it mean that the series only absolutely diverges in the interval (-1,1) and the series doesn't ever conditionally diverge?

Comment: The series converges absolutely on $(-1,1)$ and converges conditionally nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

A power series converges absolutely on the interior of the interval $(-R,R)$ where $R$ is the radius of convergence. For $|x|> R$ the series does not converge. Both of these claims follow from the proof of the [cauchy hadamard formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem). In your case for the boundary we are interested in the convergence of the series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n}{n+9}\quad\text{and}\quad\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n(-1)^n}{n+9}
$$
But these series don't converge (why?).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some general remarks, not tied to your particular example.The ratio test is guaranteed to fail at the end-points of the interval of convergence. At those points,more sophisticated methods are needed.My favourite is Raabe's test. Let $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$$ be a series of positive constants. Let $$\rho=\lim_{n \to \infty}(n(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-1)).$$ If $\rho>1,$ the sertes converges; if $\rho<1,$ the sertes diverges. Another useful technique is finding a partial sum by some method such as summation by parts and then taking a limit.